# How to detect equal rows of a matrix compare with another matrix with a 10 per cent of margin?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix and I want to compare rows of this matrix to rows of another matrix and verify if there are rows wich match them.

For example:

```
A = [ 1 2 3;...
      4 5 6;...
      7 8 9 ];

B = [ 54 23 13;...
      54 32 12;...
      1.1 2.2 2.9];
```

I need to detect that row 1 of the Matrix A match with the row 3 of the Matrix B. The rows are not equal because I want a +-10 per cent of margin.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you post snippets that can be cut and pasted some of us will cut and paste.  What you have posted isn't valid Matlab. Help us to help you.  I'm one of the lazy SOers who won't do very much typing on your behalf if I can avoid it.

Comment: Moreso, have you tried writing any code yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask this question in other forums and I get the best answer possible to me:

```
margin = 0.1;
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
B = [7 8 10; 4 5 12; 1.1 2.2 2.9; 1.101 2 3; 6.3 7.2 9.9];
k = 0;
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j = 1:size(B,1)
        if all(abs((A(i,:)-B(j,:))./A(i,:)) <= margin+eps)
            k = k+1;
            match(:,k) = [i;j];
        end
    end
end
fprintf('A row %d matches B row %d.\n',match)
```

I would like to thank all your answers and I would give you accepted answers, but I think this is the best code for me.

Comment: Just watch out for your nested for loops - they're a classic cause of slow matlab scripts.

Answer (score 3):

This code is untested, but should do it:

```
valid = all(abs(A(1,:) - B(3,:)) ./ A(1,:) < 0.1)
```

An explanation:

- `A(1,:)` takes the first row of `A`, and `B(3,:)` takes the third row of `B`.
- `abs(...)` takes the absolute value.
- `abs(...) ./ A(1,:)` gives the percentage change
- `< 0.1` ensures that each element is less than 10%.
- `all(...)` aggregates the values from the last step and tests that they're all true.

Comment: should be <=, but either way in this example you get floating point precision troubles that makes it not work. I suggest maybe: valid = all(abs(A(1,:) - B(3,:)) ./ A(1,:) < 0.10000001) or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think that my answer is most complete because it checks all possible rows. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you don't know which row of A may match with B, I wrote a for loop, which is an extension of Fabian answer....

```
for i = 1:size(A,1)
      match(:,i) = sum(abs(ones(size(A,1),1)*A(i,:) - B) ./ (ones(size(A,1),1)*A(i,:)) <= 0.100001, 2) == size(A,2)*ones(size(A,1),1);        
  end
```

match(i,j) == 1 if ith row of B matches with jth row of A

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think that my answer is most clear because it more readable. Thank you very much!